# How to slice a period of time into several slices in Joda Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to make a personal schedule manager using Java and Joda Time. The user has a certain period in a day (eg. 10am-4pm) , for each day in a month. He should be able to extract a period from his day and "add" a list of chores (ie strings) to this period. Then he will be shown the remaining portion of his day. He can extract more periods from this until he has no time periods left. He can add an extracted period back to the schedule for the day and remove all chores for that period, that is free time.

The size of a time slice that can be extracted is decided by the user. number of time slices = total time available in a day/size of time-slice set by user = num of time slices of desired size + remainder time

He can divide his day into chunks of 1hr, 30 mins, 15 mins, 20mins, 40mins etc.

*ADDED:* The user needs to have his whole schedule saved so that he can come back and check what he was doing in the past. The hours each day can be variable - 10am-4pm, 9am-1pm etc

I am new to Joda Time and I don't know if this is possible in Joda Time and if possible, is it easy or cumbersome. I only need some guidance. I am not asking for the whole code to be typed for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, reading your question. It seems to me that this is a simple logic problem. doesn't seem like you need jodatime for anything. unless i'm misunderstanding your question. You just have to maintain a static counter which starts up with the number of hours a day, and as the user creates new events, you add and subtract hours from the counter.

Comment: @greenkode - no static. Th user needs to have his whole schedule saved so that he can come back and check what he was doing in the past. The hours each day can be variable - 10am-4pm, 9am-1pm etc

Comment: I suppose you need a data structure: a start time, a end time and a string to mark things to do. Right?

Comment: @lhuang - exactly. I want it to be such that I can remove and add time chunks easily.

Comment: Main part of this problem solved here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358409/dividing-a-joda-time-period-into-intervals-of-desired-size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the updated code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

public class Schedule {

// figure out some way to Store these values in a database
static List<DateTime[]> schedule = new ArrayList<DateTime[]>();

//Number of hours in a day
static DateTime startDay = new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 8, 0, 0);
static DateTime endDay = new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 16, 0, 0);

//Create a Period from the start and End Day dates
static Period dayPeriod = new Period(startDay, endDay);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // These events will be created on your UI
    DateTime[] firstEvent = { new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 9, 0, 0), new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 10, 0, 0) };
    DateTime[] secEvent = { new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 11, 0, 0), new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 12, 0, 0) };
    DateTime[] thirdEvent = { new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 12, 0, 0), new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 13, 0, 0) };

    //print the hours left, before creating events
    System.out.println(dayPeriod.getHours() + " : " + dayPeriod.getMinutes() + " : " + dayPeriod.getSeconds());

    //Call a method to validate them
    validateAndAdd(firstEvent);
    validateAndAdd(secEvent);
    validateAndAdd(thirdEvent);

    //print the hours left after creating events
    System.out.println(dayPeriod.getHours() + " : " + dayPeriod.getMinutes() + " : " + dayPeriod.getSeconds());

}

public static void validateAndAdd(DateTime[] event) {

    //Subtract the event period from the Day Period
    dayPeriod = dayPeriod.minus(new Period(event[0], event[1]));
    schedule.add(event);
}
}
```

output from this run is

```
 8 : 0 : 0
 5 : 0 : 0
```

however, if you change the firstEvent to

```
DateTime[] firstEvent = { new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 9, 30, 0), new DateTime(2013, 03, 12, 10, 0, 0) };
```

output from the run is

```
8 : 0 : 0
6 : -30 : 0
```

Comment: Curious to know if a Period object is "aware" of its own start time and end time. I don't see any method like getStartDate() and getEndDate() in the API which can return back the DateTime-s used to create this Period. However, we have getters and setters for components of a period. Don't know why that is the case. Period merely looks like a difference or a number that is not aware of its ends. eg -2 can mean 1-3 or 7000-7002 etc.

Comment: @JediKnight I think you should do create a new data structure do achieve this.

Comment: seems like the only way to reconstruct the date from the Period is to create a new DateTime and manually pass the date values using the Period get methods, like in my system outs. see updated code

Comment: Take a look at the Interval class, it represents a slice of time with a start and end instant: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/key_interval.html

Comment: Problem solved at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358409/dividing-a-joda-time-period-into-intervals-of-desired-size

Answer (score 1):

Method split start and end in given interval.

```
private List<Interval> splitDateTime(long start, long end, int intervalNo) {
            long interval = (end - start) / intervalNo;
            List<Interval> list = new ArrayList<Interval>();
            for (long i = start + interval; i < end; i += interval) {
                list.add(new Interval(start, i));
                start=start + interval;
            }
            list.add(new Interval(start, end));
            return list;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you describe, you need to caculate the chunk length and store begin time and end time for each chunk. Through JodaTime, it is every easy to calculate a chunk's begin time and end time. It provides API like [DateTime#plusHours](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusHours%28int%29) (add N hours), [DateTime#plusMinutes](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMinutes%28int%29) (add N minutes).

For example:

```
DateTime beginTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime endTime = beginTime.plusMinutes(40);
System.out.println(beginTime);
System.out.println(endTime);
```